# i was scraping data with selenium and then want to save in variabe to convert it to dataframe

Tags: selenium, for-loop, web-scraping

```py
title= table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'title--wFj93')
for b in range(0,len(title)):
    
    print(title[b].text)

a= print(title[b].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

`print` function always returns `None`.

To create a final DataFrame you can:

- create a dictionary with key `Title` and value with title text, add it to a list
- as last step, create a DataFrame from this list:

```py
titles = table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "title--wFj93")

all_data = []
for t in titles:
    all_data.append({'Title': t.text})

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Comment: for k in range(100):
 title= table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'title--wFj93')
 price= table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"currency--GVKjl")
 review= table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'rating__review--ygkUy')
 location= table.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'location--eh0Ro ')

with open ('my_data_link.csv','a') as file: 
 for i in range(len(title)):
    file.write(title[i].text + ";" + price[i].text + ";"+ review[i].text + ";"+ location[i].text + '\n')
next=table.find_element(By.XPATH,"/?*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[9]/a")
next. Click()
file. Close()

Comment: File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_8184\3498080047.py", line 10
    next=table.find_element(By.XPATH,"/?*[@id="root"]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div/ul/li[9]/a")
                                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax